# How do I add bearer token to JMeter

Tags: jmeter, postman

I have come from PostMan now using JMeter for stress testing, I have a POST method that works great with PostMan yet I can't seem to get the bearer token authenticating to work on JMeter. I have the same token in PostMan as JMeter (See Screenshots)

Any help or advice is appreciated. See screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show header of postman?should not you provide 'Content-Type':'application/json' to jmeter header as well?

Comment: @Vova you’re right I didn’t add those in, I get Auth error which is the problem. The PostMan has Two Content-Type: application/json and another one which is application/json. 

I’m not sure that I am entering the data in the correct order for JMeter?

Comment: If you are going to use Bearer token, it's set usually via 'Authrozaiton': 'Bearer XXX',
thats, why i'm asking to take a look at headers and Authorization tabs in postman.
I just checked it on my webapp with jmeter and it works good with  'Authrozaiton': 'Bearer XXX'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're capable of running your request successfully using Postman - you should be able to record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

1. Start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/proxy/)

   [image]
3. Run your request/test in Postman
4. JMeter should capture the request and generate corresponding [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and the [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

More information: [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling)

With regards to your setup: the header name should be [`Authorization`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) and the header value should start with [`Bearer`](https://oauth.net/2/bearer-tokens/) followed by your token value

The main problem is that JMeter cannot reach the application on your local machine so make sure that the corresponding web server is started.

Answer (score 1):

For using Bearer token, you should create HTTP Header Manager, what you have already added. Then add Key/Name what is used in request, mostly it's Authorization, but we should check it out. Please, provide Headers and Authorization tabs from postman. Then, add Bearer token to Value field.
In my case I should provide one more key/value: Cookie.
[image: jMeter Simple Sample]